# How do I create a SWF to work with Adobe AIR?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, adobe

For stability reasons, I'd want to create an Adobe AIR application, that uses a local SWF placed in the same directory. I haven't figured out, how to create a dedicated AIR application for one, but I would appreciate help on how to move forwards! I haven't found any help or tutorials as to help with doing this. Tried ActionScript way in Adobe AIR SDK, but ran in to problems, that I couldn't figure out or solve.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Not enough useful info to answer you **(1)** Why does it need to be in **same** directory (what does that solve)? For example: If you want the SWF to be together with the app, then maybe just **embed** the SWF inside the app, If it must be running in a folder then use AIR itself to check current install folder and then to also write the SWF fie to disk at that location... **(2)** It's not obvious what is stopping you _"to move forwards"_ yes you got problems with code but **we can't see your screen** so we don't know what problems you ran into to.

Comment: **(3)** You need to ask a question about something . Use AIR to create your SWF then use AIR to load the SWF. Ask about any error messages you get. Also mention briefly how to recreate your problem (show any testable code for a faster answer).